# How can I get only one value with ocilib?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm getting this error:

```
  code  : ORA-00000
  msg   : The statement is not scrollable
```

This is the code:

```
  char query[] ="select max(VQC_ID) from vqc";
  OCI_Statement* st;
  st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
  OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
  OCI_Resultset* rs;
  rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
  OCI_FetchFirst(rs);
  printf("%i \n", OCI_GetInt(rs, 1));
  return  OCI_GetInt(rs, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read ocilib documentation and you will have the answer....
You need to declare the statement '`scrollable`' in order to use `OCI_FetchFirst`.
If you just want to fetch only one value, use `OCI_FetchNext`